# Firebase: Flutter App: Best methods for concurrent user updates to single document. Many users updating one document at the same time

Tags: firebase, flutter

Simple voting app:

> - users make posts
> - users vote on a feed of posts
> - each app instance sends vote result to firebase to update post document.

1. Example Path: "/posts/[postId]"
2. Votes Field: map

Currently: On Firebase I have a single document representing each post. The document contains the post data and a map field for vote results. When a vote occurs, that users app instance updates the firebase document using .updateData().

I only have about 25 users right now and updateData collisions between users haven't occurred. I've been digging through the internet looking for best practices to implement concurrent document changes with no luck. Does anyone have any recommendations for best practices? Or even some keywords for searching / resources for learning this? The limitations listed and best practices on Firebase website were not helpful.

Cheers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is only one way to safely handle concurrent writes to the same field in a document, and that's with a [transaction](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/transactions).

Comment:  Bravo! That's the term I was looking for :D .
Thanks for all your epic tutorial videos, been a great help.

Comment: What if that field is a map? and every user uses their unique ID as the key? Would this work: .update({'votes.${userID}': true})